# difference between change and revision

Tags: svn

I was wondering what is the difference between these two commands:

> svn merge -r N:HEAD url working_copy
>
> svn merge -c N url working_copy

I want only to merge what is in N into my working copy, in the first command I get what I want and far more, but if I use the second command, I get nothing.

What is the correct command line ?

And what is the difference between change and release ?

I'm a little confused with these two options, same problem with diff.

I tried to look into the redbean book, but it's a bit confusing.

If someone has a good doc to understand it, it would be helpful.

Thxs for your help,
Charles.

Comment: I forget to say that my url is a first repository and my working copy is another repository

Comment: Unless you're using a really old version of SVN or you're cherry-picking you probably don't want to be using -r or -c to merge.  Newer versions of SVN have merge tracking and can figure out which revisions to merge from related branches.  1.8 has "automatic merging" which figures out the difference between a reintegrate and a sync merge for you as well.

Comment: Yes I forgot to tell that I was cherry-picking indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per `svn help merge`:

```
 -r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                            A revision argument can be one of:
                               NUMBER       revision number
                               '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
                               'HEAD'       latest in repository
                               'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
                               'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
                               'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED
 -c [--change] ARG        : the change made by revision ARG (like -r ARG-1:ARG)
                            If ARG is negative this is like -r ARG:ARG-1
                            If ARG is of the form ARG1-ARG2 then this is like
                            ARG1:ARG2, where ARG1 is inclusive
```

So, if you use `svn merge -c 100`, that's equivalent to `svn merge -r 99:100` - the set of changes that were made in that revision.

If you've made 300 changes since the revision you're trying to merge, `svn merge -r 100:HEAD` will be pulling *every* change made between revisions 100 and 400. Which is why you're getting so much more.

In the context of performing a merge within a single repository, if you "get nothing" when using `svn merge -c N`, I would first suggest checking the log for that revision and verifying that revision N really touched the path that you're using as the source of the merge. If revision 100 changed `/branch/mybranch` and I'm trying to merge from `/trunk`, there's nothing to merge when using `svn merge -c 100`.